# Converting the ssh key

Tags: ubuntu, security, ssh, amazon-ec2, authentication

to clone my bitbucket project,I changed the /.ssh/authorized_keys content by adding my bitbucket key and I am able to clone into my bitbucket,but after that I was not able to access my server at EC2 because I have deleted the whole content of /.ssh/authorized_keys and replaced with the 
key

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDHMcFczzNgh1z97zMrpyV0b+NOU7yMSZBDuH5BhvG5XDNN2CaOiwNg2iVjIR2U5laGpGMV8VC5G2N2jevXnOFyXUoe7HUuCjGK9IeG0iBsuq8GWlqC6EY0H6JbTqQK94QJIgxB2Ib+NRGYpKiLkXBO7FR7ZIcv8cv+aZdLQgNDMQTHvcHvqK8N/swBgzW1qjp+hhnkJC5ozUhFFIDTJqxTN3v9bG4CV2qYpk8axfR003X7BRVkcFZsCSq56fJ9ueB+wnqnXSZ+9WDXDPcB8AQQQ+8jNTbAE/bgQbNpztssvsBdy8+zxe7LEMlfmM8vEoyE333jSZLtvF1q+upfxzZh
```

Now how do I access my server ? 
I have generated a key file using puttygen and replaced this code in public key and tried to login but it failed showing the error message

```
---------------------------
Error
---------------------------
Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)
---------------------------
Authentication log (see session log for details):
Using username "ubuntu".
Server refused our key.

Authentication failed.
---------------------------
OK   Reconnect (2 s)   Help   
---------------------------
```

**Note** I access bibucket in windows, ~/.ssh/ has these contents config.txt,id_rsa.pub,id_rsa,known_hosts,personalid,personalid.txt and I didn't push into bitbucket after replacing text,but I cloned the private bitbucket repository

Answer (score 2):

If the key above is the contents of your authorized_keys file then you should use the private key that you use to access bitbucket e.g.

```
ssh -i /path/to/bitbucket/private.key user@ec2host.tld
```

You can recover the public key that you normally use to access the host using

```
ssh-keygen -y -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa > ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

where ~/.ssh/id_rsa is the path to your usual privater key.

Once you have recovered the key you could use [ssh-copy-id](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-copy-id) to copy is to your ec2 instance

```
ssh-copy-id user@ec2host.tld
```

If you can't use that then copy the public key to the host and use

```
cat id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

---

In putty load your bitbucket private key into your ec2 session. Load the ec2 session then go to  ssh->Auth, click on the Browse button and browse to and select the appropriate key.

You can recover the public key from your ec2 private key using puttygen. Load the ec2 private key into puttygen  (File->Load Private Key) it will then display the public key

[image: Public Key]

which you can add to  your ec2 authorized_keys file.

Comment: I access bibucket in windows ~/.ssh/ has these contents config.txt,id_rsa.pub,id_rsa,known_hosts,personalid,personalid.txt and I didn't push into bitbucket after replacing text,but I cloned the private bitbucket repository

Comment: @ThotaMadhuSudhanRao: Are you using putty on windows ?

Comment: yes ,I am using putty on windows  @lain